# Accelerated OpenGL is not working

Tags: windows-8, drivers, opengl, hardware-acceleration, minecraft

I was trying to play Minecraft, but when I logged in it came up with this error:

> ```
>  Bad video card drivers!      
>   -----------------------
> ```
>
> Minecraft was unable to start because it failed to find an accelerated OpenGL mode.
>   This can usually be fixed by updating the video card drivers.
>
> --- BEGIN ERROR REPORT 7fe0271 --------
>   Generated 24/01/13 22:11
>
> -- System Details --
>   Details:
>       Minecraft Version: 1.4.7
>       Operating System: Windows 8 (x86) version 6.2
>       Java Version: 1.7.0_10, Oracle Corporation
>       Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
>       Memory: 420524504 bytes (401 MB) / 518979584 bytes (494 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
>       JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
>       AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
>       Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
>       IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
>       LWJGL: 2.4.2
>       OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
>       Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
>       Type: Client (map_client.txt)
>       Texture Pack: Default
>       Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
>       Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null[failed to get system properties (java.lang.NullPointerException)]
>
> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:185)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:311)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:856)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:232)
>       at asq.a(SourceFile:56)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:515)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   --- END ERROR REPORT f337c3d9 ----------

I have updated all my drivers, and everything appears to be in working order, but it still doesn't launch.

My system information: 
Processor: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D525 @1.80Gigahertz
OpenGL Version 1.1
Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC. 1215N 
Graphics Card: NVIDIA ION (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.2) (ASUStek Computer Inc)
Operating System: Windows 8 Pro 64 bit

In a program called GLview, I found something which said this:
WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB: NO_ACCELERATION

Much appreciated if you helped out.

Comment: Not enough information.  What kind of computer?  Make/model?  Did you update the drivers manually by downloading them from the computer manufacturer, or the chipset manufacturer?  For example, if you had a laptop with dual video chipsets (intel for regular use, nvidia for heavy) and you downloaded the most recent intel drivers from intel, that might disable the nvidia.

Comment: @BonGart I have updated the question with my computer specs. If you know how to solve this problem, please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any way of making Minecraft run, I have switched operating systems to Ubuntu and everything appears to be working out now.